# Accessing data from the device

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that needs to access data/information from the user's phone. For example, my app will access that the device contains the apps Facebook, Google Maps, and Candy Crush and which times the user visited those apps. How do I access information like this? Is there a certain library or package I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into UsageStats and ApplicationInfo.